# How to show localization commutes with finite products/arbitrary coproducts?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, localization

I'm trying to do the following exercise from [Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGdec2915public.pdf) on Algebraic Geometry:

> **1.3.F.** EXERCISE.
>
> 1. Show that localization commutes with finite products, or equivalently, with finite direct sums. In other words, if $M_1, \ldots, M_n$ are $A$-modules, describe an isomorphism (of $A$-modules, and of $S^{-1}A$-modules) $S^{-1}(M_1 \times \cdots \times M_n) \to S^{-1}M_1 \times \cdots\times S^{-1}M_n$.
> 2. Show that localization commutes with *arbitrary* direct sums.
> 3. Show that "localization does not necessarily commute with infinite products": the obvious map $S^{-1}(M_1 \times \cdots \times M_n) \to S^{-1}M_1 \times \cdots\times S^{-1}M_n$ induced by the universal property of localization is not always an isomorphism.

The problem I'm facing is that I have an obvious map: $\frac{(m_i)}s \mapsto (\frac {m_i}s)$, but I'm not sure how to show that it is an isomorphism, in the case of finite or infinite direct sums, let alone not an isomorphism in the case of infinite products. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701216/localization-of-modules-sums-commute) basically gets at what I'm asking, but I'm finding both question and answer fairly obtuse, especially the language about "exact functors" about which I know next to nothing.

Comment: Have you tried just showing directly from the definition that the map is a homomorphism, injective and surjective?  If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @EricWofsey Homomorphism is easy, I think I might have surjectivity, but I'm confused about injectivity.
The linked question mentions: "trying to construct a function in the opposite direction, it seems difficult to choose some mapping
$$\left(\frac{b_i}{s_i}\right) \mapsto \frac{(\phi(b_i))}{\psi(s_i?)}$$
This is essentially where I'm stuck as well.

Comment: If you're confused about constructing the inverse, you can just show injectivity directly.  If $(m_i)/s$ maps to $0$, that means that for each $i$, there is some $t_i\in S$ such that $t_im_i=0$.  Can you now find a single $t\in S$ such that $t(m_i)=0$, so that $(m_i)/s=0$?  (By the way, I forgot to mention that you also have to show that map is well-defined, but that should be straightforward.)

Comment: "If $(m_i)/s$ maps to $0$, that means that for each $i$, there is some $t_i \in S$ such that $t_im_i = 0$." From that statement injectivity should follow fairly immediately, since Vakil makes clear that for $S^{-1}A$-modules, $s \times \cdot : M \to M$ is an $A$-module isomorphism for all $s \in S$. But I'm not really seeing how you get that.

Comment: Just use the definition of the equivalence relation on fractions: $m_i/s=0/1\in S^{-1}M_i$, that means there exists $t_i\in S$ such that $t_i\cdot 1\cdot m_i=t_i\cdot s\cdot 0$.

Comment: Ok, so I've got injectivity now, but I'm still unclear on surjectivity for finite products/arbitrary coproducts. I have a sort of vague idea of how to get there, but don't see clearly how to make it rigorous.